# Como fazer uma slug de data?

Tags: html, python, aplicação-web, django

Estou tentando adicionar uma slug que converta a data para um tip em que o html aceite, porém não sei como fazer funcionar.

na parte de models.py

```
class Por_dia(models.Model):
    pedidos = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='11')
    dia = models.DateTimeField()
```

e na parte de views eu defini uma data fixa apenas para teste mas agora gostaria que ele pudesse ler o dia em que o usuario selecionar a partir de uma slug.

```
def home4(request, data):

    data= '2018-06-11'
    usr= Pedidos.objects.filter(dia=data)
    context ={'lista_por_dia' : usr}
    return render(request,'por_dia.html', context)
```

Porém não sem muito bem como declarar e fazer a sug tornar a variável "variável"

Comment: Olá! Edite o conteúdo de sua questão e adicione seu código, o que foi feito por você até o momento e suas dúvidas em relação ao que esteja errado no seu código. Recomendo fazer um tour pelo conteúdo de ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour - Saudações.

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com " usuario selecionar a partir de uma slug"?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `strptime` da biblioteca `datetime`.
Pro seu código ficaria algo como:

```
from datetime import datetime
def home4(request, data):

    data= '2018-06-11'
    data = datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')
    usr= Pedidos.objects.filter(dia=data)
    context ={'lista_por_dia' : usr}
    return render(request,'por_dia.html', context)
```

Levando em conta que data é uma string que sempre vem no formato apresentado neste seu exemplo, isto é YYYY-MM-DD.